# Marker Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I don't know what but i want to display custom marker, and it doesn't display.

Need help please.

Thank you so much.

This is my .Js :

```
    var locations = [
      ['Homexpo', 44.89589669999999, -0.5713743999999679, 3],
      ['Biganos', 44.640044, -0.9629101000000446, 2],
      ['Siege social', 44.8864352, -0.6952949999999873, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('ggmap-offre'), {
      zoom: 9,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.89589669999999, -0.5713743999999679),
      scrollwheel: false,
      draggable: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
    }

    var marker = {
        url: "http://www.verywell-web.com/sanem/img/pin-ggmap.png",
        size: new google.maps.Size(31, 40),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(31, 20)
    };
    var optionsMarqueur = {
        position: centreCarte,
        map: maCarte,
        icon: marker
    }
    var marqueur = new google.maps.Marker(optionsMarqueur);
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide more information about the code, and whats the error show in console?

Comment: First of all maybe put some errors that are showed in Console ?

Comment: This is the link : http://www.pier17.fr/maison-sanem/contactez-nous/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try do this

Add function named AddMarker

```
function addMarker(marker){
    var markerImage = {
        url: "http://www.verywell-web.com/sanem/img/pin-ggmap.png",
        size: new google.maps.Size(31, 40),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(31, 20)
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(marker[1], marker[2]),
        icon: markerImage,
        map: map
    });
}
```

And then

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('ggmap-offre'), {
  zoom: 9,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.89589669999999, -0.5713743999999679),
  scrollwheel: false,
  draggable: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var locations = [
      ['Homexpo', 44.89589669999999, -0.5713743999999679, 3],
      ['Biganos', 44.640044, -0.9629101000000446, 2],
      ['Siege social', 44.8864352, -0.6952949999999873, 1]
    ];

for(var i = 0, locations; loc = locations[i];i++){
            addMarker(loc);
}
```

Comment: That's good. Thank you so much.

Other question, i want to mask at the first view all marker, and when i click on adresse (on the left in the website), i want to display the marker.

Have you got a solution for this?

Comment: You have to add event listener on click on that address elements and then run the AddMarker method. You can hold the lat and lng in element in data attributes (for example data-lng, data-lat). You should also then make some logic to center the map to the added marker.

Comment: Have you got a typical code for this for explain me. I'm really sorry to disturb you... but i'm really really really lost in js and Google Maps API.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the icon style inside the for-loop.

Try this.

```
var image = {
  url: 'http://www.verywell-web.com/sanem/img/pin-ggmap.png',
  size: new google.maps.Size(31, 40),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(31, 20)
}

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
}
```